# Xcode: Swift Dropbox errors in Alamofire source codes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I want to use Dropbox API in my iOS project.

I'm doing this instructions:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift#install

And after `pod install`, I opened my workspace and see many errors in Alamofire. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1

[image: Xcode screen]

Comment: is pod successfully installed? i mean in terminal what message do you get after completing this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `pod install` for SwiftyDropbox, it pulls in Alamofire [via the dependency](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox/blob/master/SwiftyDropbox.podspec):

```
  s.dependency "Alamofire", "~> 3.1"
```

The latest version of Alamofire is currently [version 3.3.0](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/releases/tag/3.3.0). There's some information there under "Upgrade Notes" about how this release will only work in Xcode 7.3, due to Swift 2.2 changes. So, you have two options:

1) Upgrade to Xcode 7.3
2) Revert to an older Alamofire release

Comment: i have the same problem with xcode 8.3.1. how do i revert to an older alamofire release?

Comment: @binsnoel The latest versions of SwiftyDropbox and Alamofire should with in Xcode 8.3.1. Are you trying to install the latest versions? If that's not working, open a new issue with details.

Comment: Hi I think I know where the problem is now. I'm supporting iOS 8 in my pod file and using Xcode 8.3.1 which is Swift 3 right? but since i'm supporting iOS 8, cocoa pods automatically get SwiftyDropbox v 3.3.1 which has a dependency to Alamofire 3.5.1 , which is not yet in swift 3... I guess...